# Google Drive Android API OAuth Authentication Problem - onActivityResult returns "0"

Tags: java, android, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-drive-android-api

I am just trying to authenticate for Android Drive API.

I Generated Signed APK from Android Studio. The account get authenticated and Google Drive API Authentication works perfectly with this generated APK.

Now when I Upload this **same APK** to Internal Test in Play Console. Then the authentication fails.

__ Now Here is how I Done all this__

1) Added following in the Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

2) Implemented the Authentication like this

```
public abstract class AuthActivityStackOverflow extends BaseActivity {

    protected static final int GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    public void signIn() {
        startActivityForResult( getGoogleSignInClient().getSignInIntent(), GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                onSignInSuccess(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), requestCode);
                showMessage("Account Linked Successfully");
            } else { onSignInFailed(); }
        }
    }

    protected GoogleSignInClient getGoogleSignInClient(){
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        return GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
    }
}
```

3) I generated the debug key SHA1 and registered the credentials with API Console and then tested the app. **Its working here.** (onActivityResult returns RESULT_OK)

4) Now I generated the production key SHA1 and registered the credentials with API Console and Generated the final signed APK from Android Studio and tested on my physical device. **Its still working.** (onActivityResult returns RESULT_OK)

5) Now I published this final production APK to internal test in Play Console.

6) NOW when i download this app and run this authentication. **It FAILS, now its not working.** (onActivityResult returns **"0"**)

Is there anything that I am missing on.

Comment: What android version are you using?

Comment: 28 as target compile version and using androidX support library versions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All the steps that I carried out as stated in my question are correct. I just missed on one thing and that is I am using **"App Signing by Google Play"**.

When using "App Signing by Google Play" we need to create credential - OAuth client ID by using **SHA-1** of the **App signing certificate** inside credentials in API Console.

Now where to get this SHA-1 of the - App signing certificate?

1. Select an application in Play Console
2. Go to **Release Management**
3. Select **App signing**
4. Now copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from "App signing certificate" section
5. Create new credential inside Google API Console (Google Cloud Platform) using the copied SHA-1 fingerprint

That's it. Now when you run the application an make the API call it will **work**.

Comment: I really did not get it, why negative **vote**. After almost a week i actually found what was the issue related to my question. And thus posted the solution as answer. So that anyone with the same issue does not bang their head on wall. And yes if the answer is not correct or i need to improve it just let me know.

Comment: In App signing,I found the sha1 is the same as my local keystore sha1.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to [authorize your android apps](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) using **Google Drive API**.

> Authorizing requests on Android differs from other authorization
>   workflows because of the **integration with Google Play services**.
>
> Unlike other workflows, authorization on Android uses a `SHA1`
>   fingerprint and package name to identify your app instead of a `client ID` and `client secret`.

You must follow the proper authorization process for you to test your APK in Play console.

Here is a guideline to [generate the signing certificate fingerprint and register your application](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth).

Comment: Please look at my updated question and provide if i am missing on any thing